# I'm using LOOKUP to find the first non-blank, then adding 1. Problem arises when I add too many new rows. Can you help me?

Tags: excel

I am using the following formula to look up within my spreadsheet for the first non-blank cell above the origin cell. The first non-blank's contents are then taken and 1 is added to it in the origin cell. I'm using this to quickly be able to add new A.1 sections and have the number update without me having to punch it in. It works great for copy & pasting.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1 / (ISNUMBER(B30:B41)),B30:B41)+1
```

The problem is when I insert too many new rows, the LOOKUP Vector falls outside of the range box and I have to manually change the range in the formula.

Rather than increase the height of my range, is there a way to change my code such that it LOOKUP's the entire column for the first non-blank?

[image]

Comment: a) how is that not a circular reference? b) why was it important to omit the row numbers down the left side? c) what is the end purpose of the formula?

Comment: @user10981853 a.) I suppose it is a circular reference? It has worked mostly. On occasion I have to refresh by hitting enter in the formula box.  b.) I think it's important because if I drag or copy the formula from another cell with the same function, the range is then out of wack.   c.) The purpose is so if I add a new section, say,  between section A.2 and A.3, by copy pasting the same formula, that it can figure out what section number is above it, auto-assign it's own number, and all the section numbers below update accordingly.  (What was section A.4 becomes A.5, and so on.

Comment: Would `=countif(A$27:A30, a30)` in B30 work?

Comment: @user10981853 Wow! Yes that's awesome, thank you! That does work. However when I get down to section B, I'd like it to restart. Do I just enter a one at that point?  ![image](https://imgur.com/p9fvqsS)

Comment: No, the first *B* will restart at 1. *B* is different from *A*.

Comment: Wow thank you @user10981853, that worked! That's such a more refined solution. How do I give you credit for the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be easier than you are attempting. Use this in B30.

```
=countif(A$27:A30, a30)
```

If you change the value in column A from A to B, the counter will restart.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to perform the function you described:

This Formula is intended for Column B starting on row 30 and is intended to be extended throughout the range of B where you want the logic to apply.

```
=IF(A30<>"", COUNTIF($A$30:A30, "A"), "")
```

It first checks the A column cell for it to be 'not empty.' When it is 'not empty,'for the Presence of an "A" and increments the `countif()` and displays the count for the range starting A30 to the relative row. When there isn't an "A" present in the checked cell, it displays nothing, maintaining your apparent display pattern.

Given your image blocks out the space to the right of Column B, I cannot tell if the following will apply without disrupting other non-relative content:

If you copy a row range eg 36:41 and insert rows for the purpose of injecting content mid form.

Else, simply extend the formula further in Column B.

For me, when I inserted the copied rows, the numbering automatically adjusted per your question.